# php download csv file via web page

Tags: php, html

I am trying this simple code to download csv file via my web page but didn't work.

```
     <?PHP
      header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv'); 
      header('Pragma: no-cache');
      echo readfile('test.csv'); 
      ?>
```

the error is "internet explorer can't find "csv_download.php" the file link on my web page

```
                 <a href="csv_download.php">Click here to download the "CSV" file</a>
```

anything missing?

Comment: Your PHP file either has the wrong name or is in the wrong place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP file is not at the URL you expect.  Always set the full path where possible:

```
<a href="/csv_download.php">...
```